# Can I ask why a complete but small modern C++ program can't keep up with a C battle tested implementation?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

First thing first, I'm not talking of some algorithm where there's room for choosing a strategy or another. I'm talking of the Linux [`split`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=split&apropos=0&sektion=1) command (for what is worth, I think the code is [here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/split.c)), which takes a file and a size in input and splits the former in several files of that size (clearly the last file can be smaller than that size). [A high-rep StackOverlow user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) commented [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/751593/what-is-the-state-of-the-art-of-splitting-a-binary-file-by-size?noredirect=1#comment1430192_751593) that the job that `split` does is not an "open" job, in the sense that it's solved and there's nothing left to optimize.¹

So I thought: why not using this simple, solved, problem and try to write a program for it in C++? It turns out, it took a very short time for me to write a complete modern (in my intentions) C++ code (53 as-high-level-as-I-could-write lines of code; see more below), but it doesn't perform as well (say ~5 or more times slower). (Details are in [the question I asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/751593/what-is-the-state-of-the-art-of-splitting-a-binary-file-by-size) and [in an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/751609/164309).)

Quite randomly, today I stumbled on [Vittorio Romeo's Lighning Talk from Cppcon 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfbuJAAwA8Y), and I liked it. I mean, I can't accept that, in order to do a good job, one truly *has* to write a 1700 [LOCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code) monster, instead of relying on C++ high-level abstractions to obtain an executable performing as well.

Indeed, when Vittorio talks of bad performance he's talking of ***debug*** builds which in his opinion scare people away from C++ abstractions. But as regards optimized builds, he explicitly says

> They are zero-cost abstractions when you optimize your code

So if Vittorio is correct, that simply means I've written poor code.

And that's when I thought of asking a question like *"Can this C++ code for splitting a file in size-based chunks be made as fast as the state-of-the-art Linux `split` utility without sacrificing the use of high-level abstractions?"*.

Can I ask that question?

My thoughts:

- I guess it's fundamentally a review-my-code question, to some degree, which I guess makes it off-topic (surely on-topic for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), though),
- but it's truly a small piece of code: 53 lines of which

  - 11 `#ìnclude`s
  - 6 `using`s
  - 10 blank lines
  - **26 lines of actual code**

  so doesn't it count as *"my code is slow, what's wrong with it?"*, which I guess, phrased appropriately, is on-topic?

---

(¹) Originally [I've asked on Unix&Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/751593/what-is-the-state-of-the-art-of-splitting-a-binary-file-by-size) about [`lxsplit`](https://lxsplit.sourceforge.net/) (Linux "equivalent" of MS Windows' [`HJsplit`](https://hjsplit.it.softonic.com/)).

Comment: if you do, you'd better give enough detail to approximately reproduce what you're observing. compiler, compiler version, compile and link flags, target architecture, etc.

Comment: A performance difference like this in split is very likely due to better IO performance. Have you read the split source code and tried to understand how it handles IO compared to your implementation? A valid question could be "Why is doing IO like this faster than doing it like this"

Comment: "No you can't, and F you for asking" (voting remains weird on Meta).

Comment: @CodeCaster, what does the F stand for?

Comment: You'll have to ask Gayle.

Comment: @CodeCaster, [the singer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gayle_(singer))?

Comment: Yes. As you can see in my comment, it's in quotes, but it's not meant to be taken literally. It is hard to ask for feedback on Meta, is all I meant.

Comment: @CodeCaster, oh, ok, so you're alluding to my -11, ahah. I don't know how voting works here. It looks like there's a tendency to balance answer's upvotes with question's downvotes.

Comment: I'm all about not ignoring signals. I can fully understand that your code is slower than the split tool, that tool probably has over a decade of a head start at this point. But five times slower? That sounds a little less reasonable to me. Twice as slow, sure. Five times... that's off. That makes me suspect the method of testing being used. A common problem with performance issues questions, the testing actually being done improperly. So if you ask a question anywhere, be sure to have your facts straight and well presented.

Answer (score 11):

> so doesn't it count as "my code is slow, what's wrong with it?", which I guess, phrased appropriately, is on-topic?

It does, and is, but this still likely Needs More Focus.

> So if Vittorio is correct, that simply means I've written poor code.

No. He is correct, but what he means is "once you have verified the correctness of the code, you must compile it in release mode in order to have a fair test of its performance". Right now, the compiler is *deliberately not trying* to make the code perform as well as possible, in order to make it *easier to diagnose problems* with the code by *using a debugger*.

(This is a fundamental idea that you are expected to understand before asking about the performance of some specific piece of code; you could have asked about it explicitly, but the question would likely have been closed as needing clarity, since you were apparently not in a position to ask it meaningfully. Alternately, someone might have been able to find you an appropriate duplicate explaining the basics of release mode.)

> for what is worth, I think the code is here

Looks right to me. You do understand, of course, that this is a full-fledged program with a bunch of command-line arguments *that have to be parsed*, and then various different conditions applied to the actual splitting of the file? *Of course* it is going to end up much longer than the code that implements the actual algorithm you're trying to compete with.

You need to be able to understand the competition first before you can set yourself a fair benchmark.

> Can I ask that question?

"Without sacrificing the use of high-level abstractions" is way too subjective.

You would be better off asking directly, why the specific code you have in mind is slower than expected. You have taken the first research steps: you have identified a metric (time to perform the file splitting) and a benchmark/goal (the amount of time taken by `split` on your system, hopefully in some well-defined test condition) and, presumably, a current status (the amount of time taken by your program, in the same test condition).

Before asking, [please try to take the next few steps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592):

- Did you isolate code from `split` that does the specific part your program does?
- Did you figure out the release mode thing, so that your compiler can try to make your program run at full speed?
- Did you try recompiling the `split` code yourself, so you know if the problem isn't just your compiler?
- Did you *profile* both programs, in order to figure out the bottleneck? Do they take comparable amounts of time to do the *actual I/O work*, or is it way different? Do they take comparable amounts of time to do the *computations* (CPU-bound parts), or is it way different? Do you see bottlenecks in specific *parts* of the code?
- Did you try to look for common explanations for performance issues related to the task? For example, in order to implement this program, presumably you will need to write data to files. Did you try to look up existing questions [about I/O being slow in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042110) (I literally found that one near the top by putting `c++ io slow` into the site search)? Did you try to research concepts that are relevant to I/O performance, such as buffering?

(And after doing these things, do you still have a meaningful question?)

Comment: "once you have verified the correctness of the code, you must compile it in release mode in order to have a fair test of its performance". Yeah, but I've tested the performance and it is disappoinging, hence I've written poor code. I'm just applying de Morgan (or [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)).

Comment: "Without sacrificing the use of high-level abstractions" is way too subjective. Can you elaborate? Why is it subjective?

Comment: _Did you isolate code from split that does the specific part your program does?_ Why doing that? If my program is slower than the full-fledged reference program, how could it not be even slower than the relevant part of it?

Comment: "Why doing that?" So that you can compare apples to apples. You expressed a concern about whether it is really necessary to write 1700 lines of code in order to compete with `split` performance-wise. The answer is: clearly not, because a lot of those lines are concerned with incidental tasks and not the main point of comparison.

Comment: "Yeah, but I've tested the performance and it is disappoinging" In release mode? That wasn't at all clear from your question.

Comment: I quoted _They are zero-cost abstractions when you optimize your code_ from Vittorio and deduced that my code is badly written. Doesn't this imply that I am compiling (as far as my intentions go) in release mode? I might look up GCC's doc to see if there's other flags than `-O3` or `-Ofast` that I can use to improve performance.

Comment: _So that you can compare apples to apples_ Have you read the second part of the comment to which you replied? Why should I bother comparing apples with apples if `split`'s oranges are being faster even without removing incidental tasks? I mean, if my program was faster, I would certainly try to cut redudant stuff out of `split`, to be fair. But at the moment it seems premature, because mine is slower nonetheless.

Comment: Because part of your complaint is that you think you'll have to write 1700 lines of code in order to get a performant solution, and this is not a reasonable complaint because much of that code is **not conceptually part of the solution**. In order to calibrate your expectations, you should see this for yourself.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for clarifying this part.

Comment: Side note: Sometimes before the end of the question asking process you've answered all of your questions and don't need to post the question anymore but still have an interesting question and your answers would be of benefit to the community. In this case consider asking the question anyway and self-answering. But make sure you still follow the usual rules and keep the question focused.